# INSERT results from query into TEMP TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, temp, insert-into

ORIGINAL QUERY:

```
select DISTINCT  a.UniversalMemberID, a.Name, a.DOB, a.[First Service Date], 
(select count(b.UniversalMemberID)
      from WCV b
      where b.[First Service Date] <= a.[First Service Date] 
      and a.UniversalMemberID = b.UniversalMemberID) 
      AS  Visit_CNT
from WCV as a
ORDER by a.UniversalMemberID, a.[First Service Date]
```

Need to insert my results from above query into a temp table `#TEMP`

keeps returning this error:

> incorrect syntax near the keyword select

Comment: show what you have tried so far...

Comment: Can you post your actual query with insert statement that you are using to insert data into temp table?

Comment: First you must compose the correct `SELECT` query.

Comment: Referencing alias a from inside the subquery looks problematic.

Comment: If your `Select` statement worked as intended, all you would need to do is add an `Insert #Temp (cols...)` right before the `Select`.  But something else appears to be the issue.

Comment: RIGHT the qery runs perfectly alone... but when I add the insert into statement to create the temp it gives me that error "incorrect syntax"

Comment: @rs this is my actual query which produces results i need to put into a table:                                                 select DISTINCT a.UniversalMemberID, a.Name, a.DOB, a.[First Service Date], (select count(b.UniversalMemberID) from WCV b where b.[First Service Date] <= a.[First Service Date] and a.UniversalMemberID = b.UniversalMemberID)                         AS Visit_CNT from WCV as a                                        ORDER by a.UniversalMemberID, a.[First Service Date]

Comment: Do you have a temp table created?  Can you show us the `Insert` statement?

Comment: @Siyul temp table created. insert statement is:                   select *
into #TempTable
from
 (then I thought to insert my original query here)

Comment: Use just `Insert #temptable {select query here}`.  Or if your column structure is different `Insert #tempTable (columns) {original query}`

Comment: @Siyul think were getting closer but get this new error..."Syntax error converting datetime from character string"

Comment: There is nothing in your code that involves a conversion from string to date time...

Comment: @JoshJay figured it out! thanks for all your input guys!

Answer (score 3):

[This SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65b03/1) seems to work fine...  Is this what you're trying to do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.UniversalMemberID, a.Name, a.DOB, a.[First Service Date],
(SELECT count(b.UniversalMemberID)
      FROM WCV b
      WHERE b.[First Service Date] <= a.[First Service Date]
      AND a.UniversalMemberID = b.UniversalMemberID)
      AS  Visit_CNT
into #MyTempTable
FROM WCV AS a
ORDER BY a.UniversalMemberID, a.[First Service Date]


Select * from #MyTempTable
```

Comment: returns this error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'."

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? The SqlFiddle link works fine and it is 2012

Comment: Glad it worked, what did you have to change?

Comment: i just ran it the exact same way... i accidentally left insert into before my select... thats why i got that error "next to into"

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems with a query I always try to split it and see if is something wrong, it also may help if you try query apart, starting from generic like `SELECT *` to more filtered query.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT a.UniversalMemberID, a.Name, a.DOB, a.[First Service Date], 
(
SELECT count(b.UniversalMemberID) 
FROM 
WCV AS b 
WHERE 
b.[First Service Date] <= a.[First Service Date] and a.UniversalMemberID = b.UniversalMemberID
) AS Visit_CNT 
FROM 
WCV as a 
ORDER by a.UniversalMemberID, a.[First Service Date]
```

I will try to do the query from the parenthesis first, and start adding things. Hope it helps.

Give us feedback.

Comment: this wouldnt matter because my query runs perfectly. i just need to insert the results into a table! its so simple but keep getting this error